# Question about N iid exponentially distributed r.v's Xi (where N is also a r.v.)

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I took screenshots of both the question and answers provided, however there are a couple of steps I did not understand and i put red arrows over equal signs i didn't get. (normally there's an asterisk above the equals sign and an explanation, but none for this question).

I'm asking if someone can explain both where the formulae come from and also what's going on in the transformations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This first is [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), the second is [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance). I'm not too familiar with mgf, so I don't many theorems about, but I'm guessing there exists one such that you can take the $\log$ and get the mgf of $S$ that way. Or you can simply use the definition and I'm guessing that it can be derived in a straight foward manner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw in the first part of the answer to part 1 (E[S] = E[E[S|N]]), but can you explain how then it becomes E[NX], cause that's what I'm not getting.

Also, I've seen the law of total expectation before in the lecture slides, but this form is different. In the slides its Var(X) = E[Var(X|Y)] + Var(E[X|Y])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We note that $S = X_1 + \cdots + X_N$ is the sum of $N$ IID exponential random variables, where $N$ is itself random (Poisson).  The law of total expectation states that $$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[S \mid N]],$$ where the inner expectation is taken with respect to $X$ over the conditional random variable $S \mid N$, and the outer expectation is taken with respect to $N$.  The application is simple.  If $S$ is a sum of $N$ random variables, then $S \mid N$ is the same sum, but presuming that $N$ is fixed and known--that is to say, $S \mid N$ is the random value of $S$ *given* that $N$ is known.  In such a case, the expectation of $S \mid N$ (i.e. ignoring for the time being the randomness of $N$) is simply $$\operatorname{E}[S \mid N] = \operatorname{E}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N \mid N] = N \operatorname{E}[X] = N/\theta,$$ since each of the $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ are IID. Consequently, $$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[N/\theta] = \operatorname{E}[N]/\theta,$$ since $\theta$ is a fixed (but unknown) parameter, not a random variable.  And since the mean of $N$ is $\lambda$, we get the claimed result.

A similar principle applies to the law of total variance.  Here, $\operatorname{Var}[S]$ requires us to calculate the conditional *variance* $\operatorname{Var}[S \mid N]$, which is similar to our previous calculation above in that we assume momentarily that $N$ is fixed.  Again, since the individual $X_k$s are IID, the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of their variances; i.e., $$\operatorname{Var}[S \mid N] = N \operatorname{Var}[X] = N/\theta^2.$$  Now we combine all the results together:  $$\operatorname{Var}[S] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[S \mid N]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[S \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[N/\theta^2] + \operatorname{Var}[N/\theta] = \lambda/\theta^2 + \lambda/\theta^2 = 2\lambda/\theta^2.$$

Finally for the MGF, the thing to remember is the definition of the MGF in terms of the expectation:  $$M_S(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tS}].$$  But this expectation can be written as $$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[e^{tS} \mid N]]$$ using the law of total expectation in reverse.  And since $$e^{tS} = e^{t(X_1 + \cdots + X_N)} = e^{tX_1} e^{tX_2} \cdots e^{tX_N},$$ we see that $$\operatorname{E}[e^{tS}\mid N] = \prod_{k=1}^N \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = (M_X(t))^N = \exp \left(N \log M_X(t)\right),$$ again because the $X_k$s are IID.  Now we write $$M_S(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{N \log M_X(t)}] = M_N(\log M_X(t)),$$ and this proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks heropup for the reply. It made everything easy to understand. Sometimes the ommission of steps and explanations in the answers really make it hard for us students to follow along, particularly since this was the first question in the segment on functions of random variables. Thank you again for the quick response.